# Teamcity display error message instead exit code

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I do not know what I did and the default behavior changed so I am looking for some ideas. At the moment when this [simple Error command](https://github.com/expand/eXpand/blob/16.1/Xpand.build#L229) fails teamcity reports Exit code 1 and the only way to see the error is by navigating/search the build.log while I want to display it instead of the Exit code.

[image]
[image]